# How to Bypass OnEdit Functionality for Google App Scripts when a user Undo's a change? - Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a an app script for google spreadsheet that simply updates a status in another sheet from a dropdown. It works as expected until I press undo which then fires the onEdit(e) trigger again. Is there a way around this??

```
function onEdit(e) {

...
var value = e.value;
functionToUpdateStatus(value);


}
```

I tried to look for similar questions but couldn't find any answers.

Comment: I don't think about a workaround, but maybe you can use `e.oldValue` to detect some unexpected behaviour

Comment: @WaximCorp please elaborate.

Comment: It's still an edit event, so you have to define what you would consider an "undo" as there isn't a way to detect that. The easy way would be saying something like "if the new value is blank where as the old value was not blank, than it's an undo". The hard way is to store previous values somewhere so you could compare the new value to the value before previous. Depending on your needs you can store those in the properties service or a hidden tab for example.